# How can I override core misc js in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I have a problem with dialog in drupal 8, and I found a place that make me stuck.
There is a code in this file not work as my expected. Please see the image

[image]

I just want to do the simple thing is comment the line out like below:
[image]

I can't do this because this is core file. So I want to override this file or this function only.

I trying to use libraries-override but no hope. This is my code, I am newbie so this code may have mistake or wrong.
[image]

"capital" is my theme, not module

below is my theme structure:

[image]

Please help... I googled this issue for long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by myself:

**Step 1**: clone core js to your theme js like this:

[image]

**Step 2**: modify template library ([your-theme-name].libraries.yml)
Declare core file your need to add to your theme

[image]

**Step 3**: disable core files using your theme info file ([your-theme-name].info.yml) and add your files as library:

[image]

That's it :)
Any better idea? please suggest me more.

Answer (score 1):

Better way would be:

```
libraries-override:
  core/drupal.dialog: captial/dialog
```

Comment: Thanks for late comment, I don't have a chance to apply this solution, but thanks :)